# How to validate the integer field using xml validation using struts 1.3

Tags: java, validation

Hi could any one help me out,How to validated the integer field using xml validation using struts1.3 here is my code.

```
   <field property="geozone" depends="integer">
                <arg0 key="PointFormBean.geozone" />
<!--                <arg1 key="${var:min}" resource="false"/>
                <arg2 key="${var:max}" resource="false"/>
                <var>
                    <var-name>min</var-name>
                    <var-value>1</var-value>
                </var>
                <var>
                    <var-name>max</var-name>
                    <var-value>15</var-value>
                </var>-->
            </field>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<field property="geozone" depends="integer,intRange">
    <arg position="0" key="PointFormBean.geozone"/>
    <arg position="1" name="intRange" key="${var:min}" resource="false"/>
    <arg position="2" name="intRange" key="${var:max}" resource="false"/>
    <var><var-name>min</var-name><var-value>1</var-value></var>
    <var><var-name>max</var-name><var-value>15</var-value></var>
</field>
```